# Format loop variable in gnuplot

Tags: loops, format, gnuplot

I want to loop over the files `basename0.00.txt`, `basename0.01.txt`, ..., `basename1.00.txt`.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
plot for [t = 0:1:0.01] 'basename'.t.'.txt'
```

Because `t` is `0`, not `0.00`. I need to format it. How to go about this? I've tried using:

```
`sprintf("%3f", t)`
```

But I get:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Are the backticks supposed to be there? Otherwise I get `invalid command`.

```
gnuplot --version
# gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate only over integers:

```
plot for [i=0:100] sprintf('basename%.2f.txt', i/100.0)
```

That works fine with 4.4.4